# Add tab item dynamically not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

```
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="content-block">
    <div id="tab-holder" class="buttons-row">
      <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link active button">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link button">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#tab3" class="tab-link button">Tab 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how should i add tabs dynamically?

```
    <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link active button">Tab 1</a>
```

I made a function like this but not working:

```
function createTabButton(_holder, _text, _isActive) {
    var thm = $(`<a class="tab-link button ${_isActive ? 'active' : ''}">${_text}</a>`);
    _holder.append(thm);

    console.log(_text);
}
```

did i miss something ?

Comment: sometimes i think its easier to have them created in HTML file already then hide them in JS and show them when u need them

Comment: @Flash your idea is valid and ok; but my tabs are dynamic JSONs that should bind from server to mobile application. I think framework7 has 
 some sort of **scope** tricks something like angular !

Comment: Ok perhaps you dont get a finite answer, what you want to achieve is still achievable with hiding and unhiding tabs, if i am right from your JSON mainly u are going to be manipulating the response which is mainly text, the JQuery you are using can do the job for you changing labels and staff on the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that using only Dom7(framework7 own dom manipulator), using almost the same code that you.

Used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ as example

```
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="content-block">
    <div id="tab-holder" class="buttons-row">
      <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link active button">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link button">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#tab3" class="tab-link button">Tab 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="button">add</button>

</div>
```

Javascript - [Updated with template String]

```
var myApp = new Framework7();

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;


$$("#btnLoad").on('click', function() {

    $$.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
        data: {
            'userId': 1
        },
        type: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(){
        $$("#btnLoad").text("Loading...");
      },
        success: function(data) {
            var list = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                createTabButton($$("#tab-holder"), list[i].id, list[i].completed);
            }
          $$("#btnLoad").text("Tabs Added");
        }
    });
});

function createTabButton(_holder, _text, _isActive) {
    //var thm = $$('<a class="tab-link button ' + (_isActive ? 'active' : '') + '">' + _text + '</a>');
      var thm = `<a class="tab-link button ${_isActive ? 'active' : ''}">${_text}</a>`;
     _holder.append(thm);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexprazeres11/0cwvejcx/76/

Tested in Framework7 v1.4.2 and 1.6.4, it may work also on v2.0+.

Comment: Hi it seems works pretty well in jsfiddle. I am testing the idea in my project right now.

Comment: Ok it works great in my application with Dom7. Thanks :) but i am confused. Why my original code is not working ? is it because of jquery?

Comment: I forgot to mention this.I used this version => framework7/1.4.2 :)

Comment: Basically because of this : $(`<a class="tab-link button ${_isActive ? 'active' : ''}">${_text}</a>`);

Comment: So i think i used the ES6 **${}** feature in a wrong way

Comment: I updated my answer with working example with Template String ${}

Comment: Thanks :) its better because ${} helps to keep the code clean.